# Filter divs with jquery with one or two attributes

Tags: jquery

If there is a one class attribute in div filter is working nice. 
But if i want to add second attribute, it confuses.

I have a lot of car which are listed by divs. And child div of #parent has an attribute  which is flag for filtering.

Here is the html code:

```
<button class="active btn" id="all">All</button>
<button class="btn" id="Manual">Manual</button>
<button class="btn" id="Automatic">Automatic</button>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="Manual">something</div>
  <div class="Automatic">something</div>
  ....
</div>
```

When hit the button filter show or hide divs by the attribute.
Here is the jquery:

```
var selectedVehicleTypes = ["all"];
var $btns = $('.btn').click(function () {
if (this.id == 'all') {
    $('#parent > div').fadeIn(450);
    selectedVehicleTypes = ["all"];
    $(".btn").removeClass("active");
    $(".btn").first().addClass("active");
}
else {
    var allIndex = $.inArray("all", selectedVehicleTypes);
    if (allIndex > -1) {
        selectedVehicleTypes.shift();
        console.log(selectedVehicleTypes);
    }

    var catIndex = $.inArray(this.id, selectedVehicleTypes);
    if (catIndex > -1) {
        selectedVehicleTypes.splice(catIndex, 1);
    }
    else {
        selectedVehicleTypes.push(this.id);
    }

    if (selectedVehicleTypes.length == 0) {
        $('#parent > div').fadeIn(450);
        selectedVehicleTypes = ["all"];
        $(".btn").removeClass("active");
        $(".btn").first().addClass("active");
    }
    else {
        $(".btn").each(function (index, el) {
            if (this.id.length > 0) {
                var selector = "." + this.id;
                var btnIndex = $.inArray(this.id, selectedVehicleTypes);
                if (btnIndex > -1) {
                    $(selector).fadeIn(450);
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                }
                else {
                    $(selector).hide();
                    $(this).removeClass("active");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is working properly. But when i'm adding two options too, it confuses.

```
<button class="btn" id="Benzin">Benzin</button>
<button class="btn" id="Diesel">Diesel</button>

<div id="parent">
   <div class="Manual Diesel">something</div>
   <div class="Automatic Diesel">something</div>
   ...
</div>
```

Not working. How can i solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Selecting based on the classes should be pretty straight forward.  `$('.Automatic')` for example.

Comment: $('.Automatic') works, $('.Automatic Diesel') does not

Comment: For that use a comma `$('.Automatic, .Diesel')`  Remember the `.` in front of the class name.

Comment: Also, there is a BIG difference between `$('.Automatic, .Diesel')` and `$('.Automatic', '.Diesel')`.  The first means "get everything that has at least one of those classes".  The second means "get all `.Automatic` which are inside of a `.Diesel`.

Comment: If you want it to have BOTH, `$('.Automatic.Diesel')` notice no space between the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of examples of jQuery selectors for classes.

`$('.Automatic')`
This gets everything that has the Automatic class on it.

`$('.Automatic, .Diesel')`
This gets everything that has either Automatic or Diesel.

`$('.Automatic.Diesel')`
This gets everything that has both Automatic and Diesel.

`$('.Automatic', '.Diesel')`
This is a little more complex but it first looks are all Diesels and then says are there any child elements which have Automatic and returns those.

There are very small differences between the last 3 and those differences make a world of difference.